# unregistered user can write in blog page - possible? how to?

Tags: plugins, comments, blog

I'm working on a site wherein the owner wants people(potential real estate clients) to be able to write their home-owning hopes, dreams, desires, etc. I'm thinking something similar to the functionality of comments, like a live-feed testimonials page?

My question is how do I facilitate this? I'm not too concerned with spam right now, just want to know how to/if it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin allows posts from the front end: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-submitted-posts/

I have tested it and it worked fine, however, it is basic in that you can get the post title, content, category, tags using this, but if you want to add custom fields or anything more complex you may find a hand made solution works better such as this: http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/

Good luck!

---

Just re-read your question and it sounds like another option might be to use the comments functionality as you've suggested but you could create a custom page template where the comments were the main focus of the page, that would probably be an easier option than having users submit their comments as posts.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll definitely check out the plugin, seems a worthwhile Plan B.
I do very much like the idea of utilizing comments- probably easier to handle and moderate?- for this purpose. Would there have to be any posts involved on the page or could I utilize strictly comments?

Comment: I would create a page called 'testimonials' or whatever you want, enable comments for that page and just add instructions on the page such as 'add your testimonial below'. You could use a custom page template or some custom CSS to change the style of the comments area but that's optional, not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That's relatively simple, if you want no fancy inputs or uploads.
And even if, a basic working structure is thereupon easily expanded.

Start you mission with a simple HTML form with a text field for the title and a textarea for the post's body.
Attach the form to a page by either the use of a simple plugin, a shortcode (handler in theme's *functions.pnp*), a page template or directly via the editor. Up to you.

Thereafter have look through [the codex article on `wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) for the saving callback.